# getting error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trialrisk.urls' in python

Tags: python, django

I'm new here in `django python`, right now I'm working with rest api, So I have created new app `trialrisk`, first i have added my app in `settings.py` file, After then when I am trying to add url in urls.py file I'm getting an error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trialrisk.urls' in python`, Here I have added the whole code and my folder structure, Can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

Folder Structure

[image]

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'trialrisk',
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include('trialrisk.urls'))
]
```

Comment: which django version you are using?

Comment: there is no `urls.py` file in the app folder `trialrisk`. you need to create one to include it in the projects `urls.py` file

Comment: Either create a urls in app or just import your views in project-urls and make paths for them

Comment: It seems urls module is not defined inside the `trialrisk`...

Answer (score 1):

There is no urls.py file in trialrisk folder. Create the same in trialrisk folder and import from it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding urls.py to trialrisk, you'll also have to add a urlpatterns object to it e.g. `urlpatterns = []`, or you'll get an error like this

`raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'trialrisk.urls' from '/pathtoyourproject/trialrisk/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`